# Is there a way to modify FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING

Tags: php

FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING basically does not also allow '.' DOTs. Is there any way to make it allow DOTs too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use flags to modify its behaviour:

```
<?php
 $smaller = "dots..";
 echo filter_var ( $smaller, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH);
?>
```

You can use `FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_LOW` too.

From php source:

- FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING - Strip tags, optionally strip or encode special characters.
- FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH - Strip characters with ASCII value above 127.
- FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_LOW - Strip characters with ASCII value below 32.

Actually from php.net documentation [FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php) we don't get much information about this. So, we will get information from php source mentioned below:

[Php sanitizing filters source](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/filter/sanitizing_filters.c)

In above file look for `php_filter_string`